# Getting Ogre3D running with eclipse (windows) - how to?

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, ogre, cegui

I am trying to get `Ogre3D` to work unter eclipse (windows) with `C++`, using `CEGUI` for building the interface. Here the exact versions:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Helios), with CDT
CEGUI SDK 0.7.5 for MinGW
Ogre SDK MinGW 1.8.1
```

I followed this tutorial: http://cs.gettysburg.edu/~cpresser/cs391/ogre_eclipse_project_win.html

Even after hours of research I still get a comiling error:

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project OgreTest2 ****
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -LD:\**\**\OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-1\bin\Release -L{OGRE_HOME}\boost -LD:\**\**\CEGUI-SDK-0.7.5-mingw\bin -oOgreTest2.exe src\Tutorial1.o src\BaseApplication.o -lOgreMain -lOIS -lOgreProperty -lOgrePaging -lOgreRTShaderSystem -lOgreTerrain -lCEGUIBase -lCEGUIOgreRenderer
src\Tutorial1.o:Tutorial1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1a): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
src\Tutorial1.o:Tutorial1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x24): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
d:/**/**/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src\Tutorial1.o: bad reloc address 0x24 in section `.text.startup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

It may be related to `boost`, which comes with `Ogre SDK`. However, I can't figure out how to set it up correctly.

Any clues how to bring a simple "Hello World" at running with `Eclipse/Ogre/Windows`?

Kind regards,
Corak

Comment: Is OgreSDK shipped with built Boost.System library? A file named libboost_system*, probably in {OGRE_HOME}\boost?

Comment: In the end I was confusing the paths. Now the system works :)